# How to Apple tableView cell height based on textview size for selected cells?

Tags: uitableview, xcode5, uitextview

As you can see on the image below I have a Row that shows the Bio and another the Experience both are textviews inside a Tablecell. What i need is change the size of the cell based on the size of the textview. for this 2 fields based on a String lengh.

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (indexPath.row == 5) {

   return  bio_text.contentSize.height +10; //Not dynamic
}

if (indexPath.row == 6) {

   return  bio_text.contentSize.height +10; //Not dynamic
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: I don't see a question mark in this question.

Comment: changed my title @MichaelDautermann

Answer (score 0):

You know how tall a UITextView is because every UITextview has a ["`.contentSize`" property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentSize), which means you have that text view's height.

If you're going to display all of the text in a text view in a particular table cell, then it's just a matter of returning the text view height.  If you're need to scroll the text view (because there's simply too much content to comfortably display in a table cell), then you need to get the frame height of the text view and use that.

Comment: It does not work and it only changes 1 if y try doing another cell wont work sing it returns only 1 value.

Comment: look and see what your "`bio_text`" height is.  It sounds like it is not set properly when going in to the "`heightForRowAtIndexPath:`" method.

Comment: p.s. And I wish I made $250 per hour like your Michael Smith does, too.

Comment: Jajajaj thats a dummy data to fill the max size see how it will look when running